# Converting array of pointers from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, migration

I am C++ programmer, and I am stuck in a migration project where I need to convert below C++ code to C#. Need help on the same.

```
unsigned short** varData = new unsigned short*[ndata]; //Say ndata is 10

for(int i=0; i<ndata; i++) varData[i] = new ushort[nwp];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives you a 2D array of 16bit unsigned integers, which is probably what you try to express in C++ by using pointer to pointer.

```
  int nData = 10;
  int nwp = 3;

  var varData = new UInt16[ nData, nwp ]; //varData is of type UInt16[,]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you use unsigned short** to store 2-dimensional array of ushort. In C# you can just declare it as

```
ushort[,] array = new ushort[m, n];
```

where m and n are the dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jagged Arrays, not 2D array; if you need the same result as C++. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx for more informations.

Comment: Why should he use Jagged Arrays instead? Link only answers are discouraged, please include at least a brief summery of the information (in the event that the link ever goes dead)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Because C++ source is using Jagged Arrays, not 2D array.

Comment: It would be nice to explain that in your answer instead of "just taking your word for it" (I am not disagreeing with you, in fact I think you bring up a very good point. I just want to help you learn to make better answers at this beginning of your SO experience)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Updated. Thank you for advanced. The truth is I want to explain more than I answered. But, I'm still learning English.